# How to specify when element should wrap with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 blocks that are wrapped in flex container. I specified so that flex-row will wrap, but is there any way to clearly indicate when should elements wrap? I want to resize content inside flex-items until some breakpoint and only then wrap them.

Code looks like that:

```css
.flex-row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-row'>

  <div class="block1">

  <h2>Some title</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
  </div>


  <div class="block2">

  <img src="img"/>
    
  </div>


</div>
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use media queries to declare the flex-wrap property because without it it wont wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `min-width` on the blocks. This means they will fully stretch, but when the screen size limits them to being `200px` in this example, that breakpoint will lead them to wrap, and their width will **never** go below `200px`.

Another option is to just apply `flex-wrap: wrap;` on that specific breakpoint you want with a `media-query`.

For further control, you could also look into `flex-basis`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

### **EDIT: Responsive image**

Genereally it's good to include this line of code on most images: `max-width: 100%;` `height: auto;` as this will make images auto-responsive. `max-width: 100%;` forces the image to never overflow from its container, and `height: auto;` adjusts the images height so its aspect ratio is correct. Try dragging the screen size and you will see its effect :)

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block1,
.block2 {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.block2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-row'>

  <div class="block1">

    <h2>Some title</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>


  <div class="block2">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" />

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. Also, how to make image resize when window shrinks?

Comment: @Martinez i edited the snippet above

Comment: You're welcome :) @Martinez

Answer (score 1):

Without the flex-wrap property it wont wrap so you can use media querys to exactly define when to wrap the elements. But you also have to set the width for the flex-items.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Wrap */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .flex-row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .block1,
  .block2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-row'>

  <div class="block1">
    <h2>Some title</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350"/>
  </div>

</div>
```